# J2ME-based platform won't work on Netbeans 8 under macOS but works just fine on Windows

Tags: java-me

I am trying very hard to install this 3rd-party J2ME platform on Netbeans 8.2 on my Mac (running macOS Sierra), but it simply won't work. I have installed all the J2ME plug-ins on my Mac Netbeans app, and have tried to add this 3rd-party J2ME platform to Netbeans, but it does not recognize the folder I am selecting as a platform.

I was able to install the very same 3rd-party platform on Netbeans under a Windows 10 VM, but obviously it is a VM (Parallels) so it's really slow and sluggish, and just overall a worse experience than on native macOS.

Does anyone know how to properly install a 3rd-party platform to Netbeans on a Mac ? It would help me tremendously if I could work with this library under native macOS and not a VM.

The platform I am trying to install is the [Java ETK for eWON products](https://developer.ewon.biz/content/java-0)

Thanks

**EDIT 1** I was told the emulator is an .exe file which explains the whole thing...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the emulator is an .exe file. That would explain a thing or two...